# Creating 1bbp BMP looks pretty bad

Tags: c#, .net-core, graphics

I'm using the following code to create a 1bbp BMP file to use on an e-paper screen. The 8 pixel font isn't visible and 20 pixel doesn't look that great either.

Am I missing something or is this not the way to do this?

[image]

```
public async Task<byte[]> Create()
{
    var image = new Bitmap(480, 840);

    using (Graphics graph = Graphics.FromImage(image))
    {
        graph.Clear(Color.White);
        var fam = new FontFamily("Arial");

        var font8 = new Font(fam, 8);
        graph.DrawString(DateTime.Now.ToString("d-M-yy HH:mm:ss"), font8, Brushes.Black, 0, 0);

        var font20 = new Font(fam, 20);
        graph.DrawString(DateTime.Now.ToString("d-M-yy HH:mm:ss"), font20, Brushes.Black, 0, 12);
    }

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var imgOut = new Bitmap(480, 840, PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);
        Convert(image, imgOut);
        imgOut.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

**Update**

Added code (thanks @canton7):

`graph.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixel;`
[image]

Comment: Looks like it's drawing anti-aliassed text, and then throwing away any pixels which have been anti-aliassed to shades of grey (rather than pure black). Try something like `e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixel;` or `SingleBitPerPixelGridFit` to disable anti-aliassing

Comment: That was it thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it's drawing anti-aliassed text, and then throwing away any pixels which have been anti-aliassed to shades of grey (rather than pure black). You can see that pixels are being dropped around the curves, where you'd expect anti-aliassing, and happens more with smaller fonts, which is again what you'd expect.

Try something like `graph.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixel;` or `SingleBitPerPixelGridFit` to disable anti-aliassing (you'll probably get better results off `SingleBitPerPixelGridFit`, since it takes type hinting into account, but you will need to test, and probably test across different fonts).

```
using (Graphics graph = Graphics.FromImage(image))
{
    graph.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixel;

    graph.Clear(Color.White);
    var fam = new FontFamily("Arial");

    var font8 = new Font(fam, 8);
    graph.DrawString(DateTime.Now.ToString("d-M-yy HH:mm:ss"), font8, Brushes.Black, 0, 0);

    var font20 = new Font(fam, 20);
    graph.DrawString(DateTime.Now.ToString("d-M-yy HH:mm:ss"), font20, Brushes.Black, 0, 12);
}
```

See [How to: Use Antialiasing with Text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-use-antialiasing-with-text?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) for a couple more details.